# Laravel query count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: rrpps and clients with a one-to-many relationship. A rrpps has many clients.
I need the list of all the rrpps and the number of clients that he has.
I have this query:

> ```
>   $data = DB::table('rrpps')
>             ->select('rrpps.*',DB::raw('COUNT(clientes.codRRPP) as total_clientes'))
>             ->join('clientes', 'clientes.codRRPP', '=', 'rrpps.codRRPP')
>             ->groupBy('rrpps.codRRPP')
>             ->get();
> ```

but it shows me the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'evento.rrpps.nombre' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `rrpps`.*,
>   COUNT(clientes.codRRPP) as total_clientes from `rrpps` inner join
>   `clientes` on `clientes`.`codRRPP` = `rrpps`.`codRRPP` group by
>   `rrpps`.`codRRPP`)

nombre es un atributo de rrpps. it only works well with specifying but I need all the rrpps data. How can I do?

that is, it works correctly like that, but I need all the fields of rrpps.

```
  $data = DB::table('rrpps')
                ->select('rrpps.codRRPP',DB::raw('COUNT(clientes.codRRPP) as total_clientes'))
                ->join('clientes', 'clientes.codRRPP', '=', 'rrpps.codRRPP')
                ->groupBy('rrpps.codRRPP')
                ->get();
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, do you have eloquent models set up for these tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the selectRaw method like this:

```
$data = DB::table('rrpps')->selectRaw('rrpps.*, COUNT(clientes.codRRPP) as total_clientes') 
    ->join('clientes', 'clientes.codRRPP', '=', 'rrpps.codRRPP')
    ->groupBy('rrpps.codRRPP')
    ->get();
```

This will allow you to use raw SQL in the select rather than using `DB::raw()`.

Comment: thanks Josh for the reply. I have tried its variants and it gives me the same error. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'evento.rrpps.nombre' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select rrpps.nombre as nnn, COUNT(clientes.codRRPP) as total_clientes from `rrpps` inner join `clientes` on `clientes`.`codRRPP` = `rrpps`.`codRRPP` group by `rrpps`.`codRRPP`)

Comment: Try changing `->groupby(['rrpps.codRRPP', 'clientes.codRRPP'])`

Comment: Josh, the query works for me by putting all the fields in the table into the groupby.                 ->groupby(['rrpps.attr0', 'rrpps.attr1' .....])

Comment: Well, it's not right like that either. It returns only the rrpp that have clients and I need all the rrpp

Answer (score 0):

If you already have relationship,  you don't need to use join. Also move groupBy after get(). Just do this -

```
$data = DB::table('rrpps')->withCount('clientes')
                 ->get()
                 ->groupBy('rrpps.codRRPP');
```

And you can access it with

```
foreach ($data as $dt) {
   echo $dt->clientes_count;
}
```

Comment: thanks Amitoz Deol for the reply. I tried its variant and it gives me error. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withCount()

Comment: OOh I forgot, you need to use your model class, `RRPPS::withCount('clientes')->get()`